# Java socket hanging when inside of java servlet

Tags: java, sockets, http, servlets, arduino

So I've been trying to figure out how to send messages between my arduino and my java servlet (tomcat) and have been bumping into some problems. I'm using this code in my java servlet:

```
ServerSocket server;
    //socket server port on which it will listen
    int port = 9876;
    String message = "";

  //create the socket server object
   server = new ServerSocket(port);
   System.out.println("Server socket created");

   //keep listens indefinitely until receives 'exit' call or program terminates
   while(true){
       System.out.println("Waiting for client request...");

       //creating socket and waiting for client connection
       Socket socket = server.accept();

       BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
       System.out.println("Input stream established");

       message = buff.readLine();

       System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);

       buff.close();
       socket.close();

       //terminate the server if client sends exit request
       if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
   }

   System.out.println("Shutting down Socket server!!");

   //close the ServerSocket object
   server.close();
```

But it's hanging on the

```
Socket socket = server.accept();
```

line. I assume this is because the messages i'm sending from the arduino aren't arriving. On the arduino side of things, this is my client:

```
if (client.connect(ip, 9876)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.println("12345678");
      Serial.println("Message sent");
    } else {
      Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
```

Not much to it. Now, I've tried sending this as a HTTP POST request, but without success (surely i'm doing it incorrectly, i just don't know how to do it, i've tried for a while). I know this is probably horrifically written, but i'm very open to learning from you guys today. 
The weird thing is that this works exactly how i want it to when i put the java server code in a new regular java project. Can anyone help me figure this out? Why is it hanging in the servlet but not in a regular java project?

Comment: You don't need a socket in a Servlet. It runs *as the result of* an `accept()` performed by the container. You need to implement the `doGet()` method.

Comment: Yeah, even without really knowing what i'm doing I know it's a bad idea lol. But i do have a doGet and a doPost method and i'm actually caliing the method that creates the socket from the do get. I should just be using HTTP but I've been struggling with getting that to work

Comment: Solve the original problem, not the attempted solution. The immediate problem with your code is that nobody is connecting to the port. That's good, it means you haven't wasted any time writing the client end yet. Stop this and fix the HTTP stuff.